# OpenGL4 gl_texture_2d_array won't display

Tags: c, opengl, texture2d

I want to get started with modern OpenGL while reading the superbible book by coding a cellular automata using a 2d-array texture of size 1280x1280x2 and computing the next state to another layer in a compute shader. The idea is impiously stolen from [glumpy examples](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/tree/master/examples).

However, while having such ambition in mind, I got confused at even trying to display it, not even passing the samplers into shaders.

Below I included both, the generator, which works OK, and the piece of code that does contain a problem.

#### gen

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;


sub get_arg {
    return (scalar @ARGV == 0) ? shift : shift @ARGV;
}

my $size = get_arg 1280;
my $rate = get_arg ($size >> 1);

my $symbol = (sub { ((shift) < $rate) ? '*' : '_' } );

print "$size\n";
for (0..$size) {
    print $symbol->(int(rand() * $size)) for (0..$size);
    print "\n";
}
```

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>


// including opengl libraries on linux/osx

//include glew
#include <GL/glew.h>

//include opengl
#if defined (__APPLE_CC__)
    #include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#else
    #include <GL/gl3.h>       /* assert OpenGL 3.2 core profile available. */
#endif

//include glfw3
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GL3  /* don't drag in legacy GL headers. */
#define GLFW_NO_GLU       /* don't drag in the old GLU lib - unless you must. */
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// ----------- the program itself

GLFWwindow *g_window;

#define SIZE 1280
#define WIDTH SIZE
#define HEIGHT SIZE
#define DEPTH 2


init_glfw(const char *name) {
    // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
    assert(glfwInit());

#if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#endif
    g_window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, name, NULL, NULL);
    assert(g_window != NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(g_window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
}


typedef enum { FILLED = '*', EMPTY = '_' } SYMBOL;
load_array(GLubyte array[SIZE * SIZE * DEPTH], FILE *stream) {
    static char c;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            bool approved = false;
            GLubyte *it = &array[SIZE * i + j];
            while(!approved) {
                approved = true;
                c = getc(stream);
                assert(c != EOF);
                switch(c) {
                    case FILLED:
                        *it = 0x00;
                    break;
                    case EMPTY:
                        *it = 0xff;
                    break;
                    default:
                        approved = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            assert(*it == 0x00 || *it == 0xff);
            it[SIZE * SIZE] = it[0];
        }
    }
}


GLuint create_2d_texture() {
    static GLuint texture = 0;
    assert(texture == 0);

    static GLubyte field[SIZE * SIZE << 1];
    load_array(field, stdin);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_ALPHA8, SIZE, SIZE, DEPTH);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, SIZE, SIZE, DEPTH, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, field);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return texture;
}


display() {
    GLuint texture = create_2d_texture();
    assert(texture != 0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(g_window)) {
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture);
        glPushMatrix();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord3s(0, SIZE, 0);    glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0 );
            glTexCoord3s(SIZE, SIZE, 0); glVertex3f( SIZE, 0.0f, 0.0 );
            glTexCoord3s(0, SIZE, 0);    glVertex3f( SIZE, SIZE, 0.0 );
            glTexCoord3s(0, 0, 0);       glVertex3f( 0.0f, SIZE, 0.0 );
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        glfwSwapBuffers(g_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        if(glfwGetKey(g_window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(g_window, 1);
        }
    }
}


main() {
    init_glfw("I want to display a texture");
    display();
    glfwDestroyWindow(g_window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Could you help me to analyse the issues with displaying the 2d array on the screen, please? What I am trying to achieve is to make the whole window randomly black-and-white, but so far I ended up completely confused just adding more layers from googled solutions and man pages.

I am not asking for a working code, just a comprehensible explanation which would help me to get through this problem.

Comment: If you vote for closing, please, explain. Thank you.

Comment: You can remove all of those lines labeled "uncomment on Apple OS X" because of the way `display (...)` is written (immediate mode). That's definitely a problem and this code will not run on any Apple OS.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, the code does run on my mac, why? The problem is not even termination, it just displays the wrong thing.

Comment: It'll compile and run, but everything between `glBegin` and `glEnd`, as well as a few other API calls are effectively `nop`. You've requested a core profile from GLFW, which is the only way to access array textures ... but it makes all of those API calls invalid. Other platforms at least have compatibility profiles that allow you to use array textures and legacy stuff.

Comment: You're not using the core profile. Almost all of your calls are deprecated legacy calls. If it works even somewhat, it means that for some reason you did not get a core profile context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
> ```

That gave you an OpenGL error. Even in compatibility profiles, you cannot enable an array texture of any kind. Why?

Because you cannot used fixed-function processing with [array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) *at all*. You cannot use `glTexEnv` to fetch from an array texture. They're wholly and completely shader-based constructs.

So if you want to use an array texture, you *must* use a shader.